# ¿Que tipo de cajas son los flex-items? ¿Se pueden considerar un tipo de caja como block inline e inline-block?

Tags: css, flexbox

Los elementos `inline` no pueden tener un `width` y `height` definido pero en un `flex-container` si defino un `height`,`padding` y `margin` a un elemento `inline` estos son si aplicados.

Se puede condiderar a un `flex-item` como un tipo de caja en el que el `padding`,`margin`,`width`,`height` y `border` de los elementos son respetados?

Cuando digo que si se pueden considerar un tipo de caja me refiero a que si `flex-item` podría considerarse como si fuese un valor de display solo que definido por el container y no de forma autónoma

```css
.flex-container{
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
}
.flex-item{
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(2){
  background-color: orange;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <span class="flex-item">1</span>
  <span class="flex-item">2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: A lo mejor te puede interesar leer acerca de [Contexto de formato de bloque](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) - _Block formatting context_ en inglés.

Answer (score 2):

Todos los `display` entran dentro de la categoría de **modo de diseño** (**modelo de diseño** o simplemente **layout**), por lo que todos ellos tratan lo mismo:

> La posición y tamaño de cajas basado en la forma en la que interactúan
>   con sus (elementos) hermanos y padres.

Existen los siguientes:

- El **block layout**, diseñado para presentar documentos. El **block layout**
  contiene características de documento-centrado, como la capacidad de
  flotar(`float`) elementos o distribuirlos en múltiples columnas.
- El **inline layout**, diseñado para presentar texto.
- El **table layout**, diseñado para presentar tablas.
- El **positioned layout**, diseñado para posicionar elementos sin
  demasiada interacción con otros elementos.
- El **flexible box layout**, diseñado para presentar páginas complejas que
  pueden redimensionarse de forma fluida.
- El **grid layout**, diseñado para presentar elementos relativos a una
  cuadrícula fija (`fixed grid`).

**Referencias:** [Cajas flexibles](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Usando_las_cajas_flexibles_CSS), [modo de diseño](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Layout_mode)